# Include everything, Separate with "using"

Tags: c++, api, api-design

I'm developing a C++ library. It got me thinking of the ways Java and C# handle including different components of the libraries. For example, Java uses "import" to allow use of classes from other packages, while C# simply uses "using" to import entire modules.

My questions is, would it be a good idea to #include everything in the library in one massive include and then just use the using directive to import specific classes and modules? Or would this just be down right crazy?

**EDIT:**
Good responses so far, here are a few mitigating factors which I feel add to this idea:

**1)** Internal #includes are kept as normal (short and to the point)

**2)** The file which includes everything is optionally supplied with the library to those who wish to use it
**3)** You could optionally make the big include file part of the pre-compiled header

Comment: You can use classes from other packages in Java *without* imports if you qualify the name, for example `new java.util.LinkedList<Foo>()`. Java's `import` is more like C++'s `using`, and Java has nothing remotely akin to C++'s `#include` preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the purpose of `#include` statements in C++. They do not behave like import statements in Java or using statements in C#. `#include` does what it says; namely, loads and parses the entire indicated file as part of the current translation unit. The reason for the separate includes is to not have to spend compilation time parsing the entire standard library in every file. In contrast, the statements you're trying to make `#include` behave like are merely for programmer organization purposes.

`#include` is for management of the compilation process; not for separating uses. (In fact, you *cannot* use seperate headers to enforce seperate uses because to do so would violate the one definition rule)

tl;dr -> No, you shouldn't do that. `#include` as little as possible. When your project becomes large, you'll thank yourself when you're not waiting many hours to compile your project.

Comment: You make some good points. I added my comments to the edit section. But I will however point you to the good old Windows.h which you really only end up using a small portion of yet forced to include everything making compilation take even longer.

Comment: @Dave: I can't speak much as to `<windows.h>` 's reason for being such a large header. However, I believe the reason for this is because it allows headers in the Windows SDK to be refactored without breaking client programs. (Vista's SDK, for example, underwent massive header file changes, but user programs which `#include <windows.h>` still compile just fine.)

Answer (score 2):

I would personally recommend only including the headers when you need them to explicitly show which functionalities your file requires. At the same time, doing so will prevent you from gaining access to functionalities you might no necessarily want, e.g functions unrelated to the goal of the file. Sure, this is no big deal, but I think that it's easier to maintain and change code when you don't have access to unnecessary functions/classes; it just makes it more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I might be downvoted for this, but I think you bring up an interesting idea. It would probably slow down compilation a bit, but I think the concept is neat.

As long as you used `using` sparingly — only for the namespaces you need — other developers would be able to get an idea of what classes were used in a file by glancing at the top. It wouldn't be as granular as seeing a list of `#include`d files, but is seeing a list of included header files really very useful? I don't think so.

Just make sure that all of the header files all use [inclusion guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Billy ONeal, the main thing is that #include is a *preprocessor* directive that causes a "^C, ^V" (copy-paste) of code that leads to a compile time increase.

The best considered policy in C++ is to forward declare all possible classes in ".h" files and just include them in the ".cpp" file. It isolates dependencies, as a C/C++ project will be cascadingly rebuilt if a dependent include file is changed.

Of course M$ compilers and its precompiled headers tend to do the opposite, enclosing to what you suggest. But anyone that tried to port code across those compilers is well aware of how smelly it can go.

Some libraries like Qt make extensive use of forward declarations. Take a look on it to see if you like its taste.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be confusing. When you write C++ you should avoid making it look like Java or C# (or C :-). I for one would really wonder why you did that.

Supplying an include-all file isn't really that helpful either, as a user could easily create one herself, with the parts of the library actually used. Could then be added to a precompiled header, if one is used.